# Pass a ruby &block using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-block

I want to test the functionality of the method using rspec that receives anonymous block and not raise error. Below is my code:

```
class SP
  def speak(options={},&block)
    puts "speak called" 
    block.call()
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts e.inspect()
  end  
end


describe SP do
  it "testing speak functionality not to raise error" do
    sp = SP.new
    sp_mock = double(sp)
    expect(sp_mock).to receive(:speak).with(sp.speak{raise StandardError}).not_to raise_error
  end  
end
```

It is below throwing error

```
SP testing speak functionality not to raise error

 Failure/Error: expect(sp).to receive(:speak).with(sp.speak{raise StandardError})

   (#<SP:0x007fead2081d20>).speak(nil)
       expected: 1 time with arguments: (nil)
       received: 0 times
 # ./test.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Spent a lot of time browsing articles of ruby blocks and ruby documentation but can't figure out.

Comment: You don't need to put "EDITED" in your posts. This is not reddit. We can see full history of post edits.

Comment: Your expectation is for sp_mock to be called with with speak, but you are not calling sp_mock.speak in your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too complicated for no reason. Did you mean this?

```
it "testing speak functionality not to raise error" do
  sp = SP.new
  expect {
    sp.speak {raise StandardError}
  }.to_not raise_error
end
```

Comment: yes i can do it like this but my motive is to pass a block to a function using rspec

Comment: @OJASJUNEJA: what would you hope to accomplish with that?

Comment: @OJASJUNEJA you can't pass anything with rspec. The `expect to receive` construct only sets an expectation. And you can get/call a block that was passed to you. But the actual invocation must be done by "regular ruby".

Comment: Actually it is just a demo of my real work. I cant post it here. I have function which takes &block as parameter and call that block in its definition. I know how to write rspec test case. I am just not able to pass a block to a function using rspec

Comment: but we have rspec receive(:method).with()...
source:https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Comment: @OJASJUNEJA: Yes, and that is not calling/passing anything.